# Clean Project and few options are disabled in Android studio after application crash

Tags: java, android

Unfortunately my android studio got crashed due to the power failure and when I restarted my android studio few options like

- Clean Project
- Run app
- Debug etc ., were not working properly and also disabled.

Disabled options:

[image: Disabled options]

Please let me know if any workaround is there

Comment: is your gradle building or doing something ? also, is your project opened ?

Comment: start your Android studio with `Run as administrator`

Comment: Yes my project is opened already and gradle build is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be an issue due to the crash of android studio. Please go to the "SDK manager" and select Plugins options from the left side panel and select all the plugins which were displaying with error symbol and click ok. This might solve your issue.

[image: Solution for disabled options]